# SQLite managing tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm designing a simple art quiz game. As you can see below picture; there is different categories. My question is; to store questions in sqlite database, should I create 9 different tables for each of period or should I create only one table and put all the questions into a list and then access questions using their id.(0 to 9->ancient greek, 10 to 20-> ancient rome etc.)  Which one will be more efficient?

(click Home Page to see the picture)

[Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTK2Q.png)

Comment: One table for the questions is fine. Just add an id field for the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not have a separate table for categories and another one for questions? then have a category_id column in questions which is a foreign key to a category from the categories table. . .

that way you can have more categories later and you can add questions to any category whenever you want (without the restriction of 10 questions per category). . .

P.S. as for efficiency , you are speaking of 9 categories * 10 questions = 90 rows this too little to start worrying about efficiency. but anyways you can create an index on the questions table using the category_id column, since I think category_id will be the most used in your queries.

Comment: Correct. Questions and Categories. Linked by an id.

Comment: @fulya , you are welcome, see the edit since you asked about efficiency. . .